# read and EAGAIN

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, sockets

I am using non-blocking client socket to read data from.

Sometimes read returns EAGAIN.

What is the proper way to handle it?

At the moment my code retries immediately forever. Little worried about it since there is the potential of an endless loop if read keeps returning EAGAIN.

```
s = socket(...);
ioctl(s, FIONBIO, ON);
select(s+1, r, NULL, e, NULL);
if (FD_ISSET(s, r)) {
  ret = read(...)
  ret = read(...)
  ret <---- is EAGAIN sometimes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you get an EAGAIN, you should stop reading, and select on the socket again. select will tell you when you can read more.

Comment: Ah great! Thanks, essentially that is what I am doing right now but the sample above did not illustrate that.

Comment: What about EINTR? Not sure if I should treat this error as a retry or as a connection down?

Comment: `EINTR` means a signal was received while the system call was in progress.  How you handle it depends on the signal and what you want to do.  For the most common ones, `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` you probably want to terminate your program in a controlled way, which means in this bit exiting the read loop.

Answer (score 0):

From the tag of this post, I assume you tried this piece of code on iOS. EAGAIN means to try again on most of the platforms. However, it means Resource temporarily unavailable. You can find the reference here. http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html

In terms of the proper way to handle it, you may find the way that CFNetwork applies. Please take a look at **_SocketStreamRead** in CFSocketStream.c http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-129.13/Stream/CFSocketStream.c

The idea of the handling is not to treat EAGAIN as a normal error. Instead, by clearing the read flag and continue the loop, the procedure will eventually leads to a POSIX Error 110. With this error, you can do the recovery from the upper stream level.